# How to show admob ads vertical in landscape mode? (Android)

Tags: android, admob, ads, xml-layout

I want to show the admob ads like the following. My game is locked in landscape mode, and I want to show the ads vertically. I used the XML layout to placed my ads.

[image]

Comment: Not yet, now I used other way to place my adview, but I also want to know how to place the adview like this.

Comment: could you share your code? I am trying to do the same thing and somehow it doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this, you would have to create a custom `View` that extends the AdMob View, then override the `onDraw()` method.  Because there is no source code available for the AdMob View (that I know of), however, this may be impossible.  If you had the source of the AdMob `onDraw()` method, it could be simply an issue of swapping the x and y variables.

Another option is to keep your Activity in Portait mode, and then override your own Views' `onDraw()` method to draw it in landscape. This would be a lot of work though, as you'd have to create your own custom views for buttons, image layouts, etc.