# How to show vertical admob ads on ladscape mode (using libgdx)?

Tags: android, libgdx, admob, landscape

I want something like this two other questions:
[Android AdMob Vertical ads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12644878/android-admob-vertical-ads)
[How to show admob ads vertical in landscape mode? (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684097/how-to-show-admob-ads-vertical-in-landscape-mode-android)

And I start from this:
https://github.com/TheInvader360/tutorial-libgdx-google-ads

**I tried so hard to put left side vertical banner on landscape mode, but I only get vertical admob at the center of screeen, I can't move it to the left.**

Also, **I am doing it in two differents "layers"**: banner overlap app view. I want this because I need full screen for app view.

**Another point:** I need to pause and resume app to show the banner, seems "layout.bringChildToFront" called before ad is loaded so not working.

(I have nothing special at **AndroidManifest.xml**, I am trying to do it by code)

```
<activity 
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
    />
```

**Here is my code**: (I'm using LIBGDX)

```
    public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {

      private static final String AD_UNIT_ID_BANNER = "ca-app-pub-7938591782705263/4150532439";

      protected AdView adView;
      protected View gameView;


      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        cfg.useAccelerometer = false;
        cfg.useCompass = false;

        // Do the stuff that initialize() would do for you
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

        FrameLayout layout = new FrameLayout(this);//base container layout
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        layout.setLayoutParams(params);

        AdView admobView = createAdView();//ads the banner and the app view to the base layout 
        layout.addView(admobView);
        View gameView = createGameView(cfg);
        layout.addView(gameView);

        setContentView(layout);
        startAdvertising(admobView);
        layout.bringChildToFront(admobView);//this is currently not working, I need to pause and resume app to show the banner

      }

      private AdView createAdView() {
        adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID_BANNER);
        adView.setId(12345);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.LEFT|LinearLayout.FOCUS_LEFT|Gravity.TOP|LinearLayout.FOCUS_UP);

        //last hard try to get vertical banner at left side :/
        adView.setRotation(270);
        adView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        adView.setTop(0);
        adView.setLeft(0);
        adView.setRight(0);
        adView.setX(0);
        adView.setY(0);
        adView.refreshDrawableState();
        adView.setLayoutParams(params);
        return adView;
      }

      private View createGameView(AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg) {
        gameView = initializeForView(new Main(), cfg);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        gameView.setLayoutParams(params);
        return gameView;
      }

      private void startAdvertising(AdView adView) {
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
      }


      @Override
      public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (adView != null) adView.resume();
      }

      @Override
      public void onPause() {
        if (adView != null) adView.pause();
        super.onPause();
      }

      @Override
      public void onDestroy() {
        if (adView != null) adView.destroy();
        super.onDestroy();
      }
(...)
```

Thankss a lot and have a nice day !!! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Solved by having `FrameLayout` containing `GameView` and a relative layout which contains `AdView` with relative layout params (wrap content and align parent left) and changing rotation pivot then `rotateview` works fine.

But ad still not visible, I tried this: [Admob ads appear only after first refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25485606/admob-ads-appear-only-after-first-refresh) and didn't work. I have to press home and resume app to see the ad...

Comment: Can you please explain this answer in detail maybe with the sample code